# Difference between field with asterisk and dynamicfield in solr schema

Tags: solr

I am using a dynamic field in Solr (v7.7):

`<field name="removed_*" type="pdate" ... />`

I noticed in [the documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/dynamic-fields.html) that it references a `<dynamicfield />` tag instead

`<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`

Does this make any difference, or am I just using an older backward compatible version of this field type?